# Does anyone know how to remove "Trojan:HTML/CryptoStealBTC" from Windows 10 DELL laptop?

Tags: security, networking, executable, false-positive, trojan

[image: snip of the threat]
[image: Affected Items]

I have tried all ways to Quarantine, Remove the said threat from my system using Windows Security System. Still it is coming up as a threat to the system. If anyone knows how to affectively remove this threat from the system it would be of great help. I read somewhere in Reddit that it could be a False Positive and appearing on Dell Laptop only. Anyone knows how to completely remove it from the system, so I don't see the red cross in the Windows Security System ?

Here's the link of the same question at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1707776/1672604)

Comment: Not really a programming question. Try asking at [su].

Answer (score 2):

I uninstalled the DellSupportAssistRemedationService.exe and did not reboot. I check for updates and it auto applied a Security Intelligence Update KB 2267602. Ran a quick scan - no threat found. Running a full system scan now - Will update as soon as scan completes.
We have 3 dells so far in our forest with this alert. Pretty much the same as what everyone else is reporting

Update: Full system scan came back without threats found. I dont really know if the Assistant needs to be uninstalled but will check on next PC I have with threat. I am also running an offline MS AV Scan to verify.

Update2: Offline scan did not find anything. looking more and more like a false positive. Running online full scan after reboot again then will move to second PC.

Update3: Scan came back clean. Updated 2nd PC and running full scan without removing assistant. (Had to check for updates for PC to apply it)

Last Update: So looks like just applying the patch will fix the problem. No need to uninstall MS Assistant. **Appears to be Mis-config issue.  I am going to monitor these PCs though because - like everyone else - the reg edits are concerning a little.

Comment: After removing the SupportAssist.exe the threat was still in there in my case. The problem got fixed after I rebooted the system after sometime. Glad it was a false positive. Thanks for the updates!